# Undertermined coefficients equation $y^{iv}+k^{4}y=e^{kt}+\sin(kt)-e^{-kt}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How do I use the method of undetermined coefficients to find the general solution of the equation:
$$y^{iv}+k^{4}y=e^{kt}+\sin(kt)-e^{-kt}$$

I don't have any progress in this one, because I really don't understand how to do it.

Comment: Is $y^{iv}$ $y^{(4)}$ ? Did you solve the homogeneous equation ? Show your work, please.

Comment: I have nothing for this one, I quite simply don't know what to do.

Comment: So, I am afraid that you will not get much help on this site.  I am surprised that youdid not solve  the homogeneous equation; it is simple.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.